# Copying DynamoDB table to another DynamoDB table with transforms

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

I have two DynamoDB tables: Table_1 and Table_2. I am trying to deprecate Table_1 and copy information into Table_2 from Table_1, which has different GSIs and different LSIs.

Table_1 attributes are: Id, state, isReused, empty, normal

Table_2 attributes are: UserId, Status, isOld, normal

Id maps to UserId, state maps to status, normal maps to normal, empty is dropped from Table_2, and if the state is "OLD" then isOld sets to true.

What is the best way to export this data from Table_1, do the transform on the attributes/data, and then load the information back into Table_2?

Currently, I am able to use AWS Data Pipeline to import/export data from Table_1 to Table_2 with the given templates, but this does not do the transforms. I'm guessing that I need to use EMR to do the transforms.

I also use DynamoDB streams to keep the table in sync, but from my understanding, DynamoDB streams only streams updated information, not information that already exists in a table.

Comment: Datapipeline is not the solution, explore dynamo DB streams

Comment: @Shibashis streams only gives updates/modifications to the original table, not the pre-existing data. I currently use DynamoDB streams to keep new updates in sync.

Comment: You may have to create a custom EMR job for this. Data pipeline is a EMR job minus the customization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you need this data movement only once, I can think of two options:

- Spawn an EMR cluster with Hive installed. Create two Hive tables, one each on Table_1 and Table_2. Then, do something like 'insert into Table_2 select ... from Table_1'. This will give you full control on the transformations you need.
- It is true that only updated and new items are sent to a DynamoDB stream. If you already have a syncer setup, why don't you 'update' all existing items in Table_1 once? Just add a dummy field to all of them, so that they are pushed to Table_1's stream, after which they'll be automatically copied to Table_2! Just make sure that your syncer ignores this dummy field. Advantages of this approach:

  - Will handle race conditions well.
  - Based on your business logic, you can quickly check if an item in Table_1 has already been synced to Table_2. This gives you the freedom to copy only those items in Table_1 that haven't been updated in Table_2 yet.

Comment: Both options make sense, but option 1 seems safer as Table_1 is still a live table and is an authoritative data source. For Option 1, since there are still updates being made to individual items on Table_1 while the EMR job/transformations are running, would you recommend ceasing to process DynamoDB streams while the backfill is occurring? Then once the backfill is complete, process the DynamoDB stream updates again? Otherwise, updates to items on Table_1 during the backfill might not be reflected in Table_2.

Comment: 'would you recommend ceasing to process DynamoDB streams while the backfill is occurring?': i don't think how that would help in race conditions. for e.g., there are 1000 items (i1, i2, ... i1000). EMR processed i1 to i500. now, two updates come, for i5 and i600. since EMR hasn't processed i600 yet, that item's updated value will be copied to Table_2. but your stream will have both of them

Comment: 'Table_1 is still a live table and is an authoritative data source': that is precisely the reason, I think, option #2 would be better. I am updating my answer with its advantages.

Comment: P.S. do 'upvote' and 'accept' the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Data Pipeline and writing EMR jobs, you can write a script to query all the items in Table_1 and do a transform in Java. After doing the transform in Java, do a conditional put [1] to only update the item in Table_2 if it doesn't exist. This will make sure that any changes that are made in Table_1 during this backfill will show the latest information in Table_2.

(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html)

Comment: Since I was already writing lambda scripts to read/write my table, I just temporarily co-opted one of them to do this and it worked like a champ. Thanks for the (feels like it should have been obvious) idea.